# why am I getting the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, calendar, integer, typeerror

I'm trying to make a program that prints a calendar but its not printing what I Want it too.

It's suppose to print:

```
              Month                       
Sun  Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat
            1    2     3     4    5    
 6    7     8    9    10    11   12 
13   14    15   16    17    18   19 
20   21    22   23    24    25   26 
27   28    29
```

but instead its printing:

```
              Month                       
Sun  Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat
for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [    for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [    for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [    for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [    for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [
```

This is what I have, can someone help with what's wrong?

```
while (month != "January" and month != "February" and month != "March" and month != "April" and month != "May" and month != "June" and month != "July" and month != "August" and month != "September" and month != "October" and month != "November" and month != "December"):
    print ("Thats not a correct response, please try again. ")
    month = input("Enter the name of the month: ")

week = input("Enter the day of the week the month begins (1-7): ")

while (week != "1" and week != "2" and week != "3" and week != "4" and week != "5" and week != "6" and week != "7"):
    print ("Thats not a correct response, please try again. ")
    week = input("Enter the day of the week the month begins (1-7): ")

numDays = input("Enter the number of days in the month: ")

while (numDays != "28" and numDays != "29" and numDays != "30" and numDays != "31"):
    print ("Thats not a correct response, please try again. ")
    numDays = input("Enter the number of days in the month: ")
           
name = month
days = numDays
start = week

c = [" for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [" for x in range(35-(days+start-1))]

print("{:^50s}".format(name))
print("\t".join(["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat"]))
for x in range(0,len(c),7):
    print("\t".join(c[x:x+7]))
```

Comment: If this is a straight copy, you have a syntax error where you're declaring the `c`. There are redundant double quotes.

Comment: So how would I fix it

Comment: How you fix it depends on what exactly you want (or what you were trying to do) in the first place. What do you want your first list comprehension (`[" for x in range(start-1)]`) to give you? What is `c` supposed to end up as?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the line here:

```
c = [" for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)]...
```

Python is looking for a string because you used `"`. Remove them and the space after/before them and your code should work!

Edit:

The line should look like this:

```
c = [for x in range(start-1)] + [str(x) for x in range(1,days+1)] + [for x in range(35-(days+start-1))]
```

Comment: but then it says invalid syntax